# How to install wkhtmltopdf patched qt without compiling?

Tags: qt, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-8

I'm using google cloud instance for host Odoo, somo reports print to pdf ok, but other with custom paperformat get the following error:

"The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"

I google it, and to solve I need to compile wkhtmltopdf like this: 
http://www.grobak.net/id/blog/how-fix-wkhtmltopdf-failed-error-code-6 but this proccess need 3 hs and I'm building a script to install google instances on the run with odoo dependencies.

the .deb package have a dependency broken

Anyone know other solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My system configuration is Ubuntu 14.04 and 64 bit. So, i am downloading according to that.

First you have to check your system OS name by

```
lsb_release -a
```

Check to see if your Ubuntu Linux operating system architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit, open up a terminal and run the following command below.

```
file /sbin/init
```

Download wkhtmltopdf patched with qt using below command

```
sudo wget -P Downloads https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Here, replace "trusty" with your OS name and if 64 bit only then keep "amd64" like that , otherwise change it to "i386" and down load the deb file.

After that execute the following commands,

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Now, check wkhtmltopdf version with below command,

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: doesn't work with jessie becouse   Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.

Comment: Under Debian jessie 8.6 installat depends package before install:
apt-get install xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi

Comment: The trusty amd64 package works on 16.0.4. Thank you!

Comment: The wget url is no longer working. Check https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html to find the URL for the package you need

Comment: The current version (12.5-1) needs the `xfonts-75dpi` package installed as well

Answer (score 8):

After trying many ways I finally made it work.

First I removed all my previous installation by

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Then I opened wkhtmltopdf.org and navigated into their Downloads > Archive. In Archive section I downloaded 0.12.1 .deb version by

- `wget <copy the link from website for the.deb file and paste it in terminal here>`.
- `sudo dpkg -i <package name>`
- `sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin`

This is because odoo looks for wkhtmltopdf in `/usr/bin` directory otherwise gives IOError. I also set my `webkit_path` parameter in Odoo System Parameters to `/usr/bin`.

Thats it. Hope this helps

Comment: Forgetting 1 another binary:
`sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4

installed new version of wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6-1

follow below commands to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6-1

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm

yum localinstall wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm #centos specific command
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which (while not strictly answering the OP) might be relevant for some: You can redirect to a docker image, e.g. [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf):

```bash
docker pull surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.18.0-0.12.6-full
alias wkhtmltopdf="docker run --volume '/tmp:/tmp' surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.18.0-0.12.6-full"
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com /tmp/google.pdf
```

or as a script executable in the same way as the alias:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --volume '/tmp:/tmp' surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.18.0-0.12.6-full "$@"
```

Notice the mount of `/tmp` which is necessary to enable wkhtmltopdf to read and write files on the host.