# Laravel: Trying to generate pdf -> sh: 1: wkhtmltopdf: not found - Can I register wkhtmltopdf for the shell?

Tags: php, web-hosting, ubuntu-18.04, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-5.8

So I'm in the process of getting into a project that already exists, including hosting it.
I've got all the source code (have yet to transfer the files from the old hosting)

The webpage is hosted on a Plesk Onyx 17.8.11, OS Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS‬. 
Most of the website runs like a charm, sans anything that includes loading files and the generating of pdfs (maybe other stuff I haven't found yet).
When I want to generate a pdf (using a queue worker), I get the error `sh: 1: wkhtmltopdf: not found` in my laravel.log, which points to the line of code that catches any errors thrown in the pdf-generation.

wkhtmltopdf is installed via composer (and also in the composer.json), both in the project and globally. I already searched the web, and found the hint to use the binary option. However, since the codebase is not exactly small, and I know it runs fine on another host, I don't want to change all instances of `generatePdf()` to include the option. Because it runs on another server, it feels like there's some configuration I'm getting wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I had to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617491/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-patched-qt-without-compiling), now it works like a charm.

Comment: Hi @Pixelprotagonist, First thing I would suggest to cross-check the Old hosting environment and the new hosting environment i.e. OS, Laravel/PHP versions etc.
Second, I would like to know which package it has used for creating PDF and for loading the Binary file? you can get it from composer.json.
Third, I also want to know the way you have transferred the code from old hosting to new one? simply moving all the files OR cloning the repo and installing dependencies on new hosting.

Comment: Which wkhtmltopdf package did you install? One of them has the wkhtmltopdf binaries, the other doesn't (you'd need to install the binaries manually). If  you have the binaries, where are they installed and where is the script trying to locate them?

Comment: @cOle2 came to the rescue. I only installed wkhtmltopdf via composer. Now I have a whole new error to resolve :)
 
@sssuri Unfortunately I don't know the old hosting environment too well. composer.json says `"mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.4"` and also   ' `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0"`, though I'm not sure it's used. I got the source code as a zip cloned from git, uploaded it into a new repo and cloned it from there onto my host, running composer install etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint from @cOle2, I got wkhtmltopdf via `apt-get` instead of composer. This made wkhtmltopdf usable from anywhere and lead me to another error: `The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display\nCould not connect to any X display.` This error lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617491/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-patched-qt-without-compiling), and reinstalling wkhtmltopdf as described there fixed the problem.

tl;dr Install wkhtmltopdf as binary WITH patched qt.